# Is KnockoutJS "global safe"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Does [the KnockoutJS library](http://knockoutjs.com/) rely on any global state other than the global `ko` object?  Or are there time where it may add/subtract other items from the javascript enviornment's global state (i.e. the `window.` object in the browser)

I'm asking because I'm creating a piece of software that will be deployed into web site/CMS environments.  I'd like the piece of software to be self contained, and not rely on external CDN resources.  I'd like to use KnockoutJS in this piece of software, and ensure my use of KnockoutJS doesn't conflict with any instances of KnockoutJS the web site/CMS environments are using.  I do not want to conditionally load an external KnockoutJS resource, as I'd like to ensure the version of Knockout **my** software is running is what I think it is.

I have a similar requirement for jQuery -- and I know I accomplish this by modifying a jQuery library to export a different global variables -- i.e. `var myJquery=...`.  I'd like to do the same thing with Knockout's `ko` variable -- but if KnockoutJS relies on global state this won't work cleanly.

Comment: The proper way of avoiding jQuery conflicts is to use the `.noConflict()` API provided for the purpose.

Comment: @Pointy I appreciate you engagement, but I'm not sure you understand the problem I'm trying to solve.  Web Site A uses jQuery 1.8.  My software, a non-production development tool, needs to use jQuery 1.9.  I can include a slightly forked jQuery using the technique described above.  This make sure the web site is still running against its own jQuery 1.8, and I can run my code against jQuery 1.9.  It's not the standard use case for sure, but it is a technique common in the commercial extension business.

Comment: The `.noConflict()` API is in fact designed to accommodate exactly what you describe. When jQuery initializes, it saves any values it finds for both `$` and `jQuery`. Calling `jQuery.noConflict(true)` returns those global symbols to their original values. You can retain a reference to *your* jQuery however you like.

Comment: @Pointy Not really, but I can see why you might say so. The jQuery documentation may mention running two jQueries, but it also includes the warning "which is not recommended", and assumes you're in full control over which is the second jQuery.  The problem with trying to use noConflict with the scenario above is I have no control over when jQuery will be pulled in. Is it before, or after the web site's jQuery?   The fork technique its safer, more reliable, and produces far fewer support requests for this specific instance. Useful information about `jQuery.noConflict(true)` -- thanks for that!

Comment: If your jQuery is first, then you call `.noConflict(true)`, and it has no  effect. Your code then uses *your* reference to jQuery. If the alien jQuery is first, then the call to `.noConflict()` restores the old environment, and you again use only your own reference. However, you may do as you please, and modifying the library will obviously work fine.

Comment: @Pointy And if there's another third party module that's also monkeying with jQuery in a similar way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the KnockoutJS library rely on any global state other than the global ko object?

Nearly not at all. The only two points besides exporting `ko` to `window` that I know of:

1. In a few places it checks for the existence of (a minimum version of) `window.jQuery` and uses that over built in features.
2. In some places (e.g. [the component default loader](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/241c26ca82e6e4b3eaee39e3dc0a92f85bc1df0c/src/components/defaultLoader.js)) it checks for the existence of require libraries and uses them (in a supposedly library-agnostic fashion).

But KO will not *modify* the `window` (apart from adding `ko`) in any places, AFAIK.

> I'd like to use KnockoutJS in this piece of software, and ensure my use of KnockoutJS doesn't conflict with any instances of KnockoutJS the web site/CMS environments are using.

That's a whole other issue. There are two main problems with having multiple parts of an application both use KnockoutJS without knowing about eachother:

1. The share the DOM, in ways that they might conflict. Easiest example would be that the CMS might run `ko.applyBindings` on the `body`, so any plugin wanting to have a different version of KO handle its part of the DOM will have issues. Impossible to give generic advice here, this all comes down to context and specifics.
2. Loading two seperate versions of Knockout. Obviously, if you do *nothing*, the second version loaded will overwrite `window.ko`. There should be workarounds for that though, but you may have to dive into [KO's source code](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/tree/master/src). Basically, you allude to this in your final paragraph.